# Coherent sheaves on a non-singular algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Grothendieck wrote in his letter to Serre(Nov. 12,1957) that every coherent algebraic sheaf on a non-singular algebraic variety(not necessarily quasi-projective) is a quotient of a direct sum of sheaves defined by divisors.
I think "sheaves defined by divisors" means locally free sheaves of rank one(i.e. invertible sheaves). How do you prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is proved for any noetherian *separated* regular schemes in SGA 6, exposé II, Corollaire 2.2.7.1 (I learn this result from a comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109903/): such schemes are "divisorial".) To see that this answers your question, look at op. cit. Définition 2.2.3(ii).